# NSString displays in NSLog, but it changes its coding after adding to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have NSString with text(Ukrainian language). Then I print it in log. Everything is ok. Then I add this string to NSMutableArray and then I print in log that array. And when this string prints as part of array it changes its coding and I get a set of symbols without sense(with english text everything is ok).

My code is the following:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
    [materials addObject:newString];
    NSLog(@"%@",materials);
```

But in log I have:

```
2015-08-13 16:19:46.689 ShopIC[343:29722] Хлопок.80
2015-08-13 16:19:46.689 ShopIC[343:29722] (
    "\U0425\U043b\U043e\U043f\U043e\U043a.80"
)
```

How is it possible to solve?

Comment: Try this:      NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [materials objectAtIndex:0]] );

Comment: (see if it's still doing it after being put back to object type NSString)

Comment: @Ben yes, now it's working!) Thank you a lot, I have to study stronger...Maybe it would be better to delete this question, because it was duplicated?

Comment: nah, it's fine, someone might use the same wording as you :)